# Structure the first few pages in a thesis

Tags: titles, thesis

The first few pages in a thesis or report seem to be not so easy for a Latex beginner. I read the [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280), however, it didn't show how to do the next few pages often appeared in a thesis and the text in the title page seem not centered. Recently, I am trying to customize my titlepage and find a good [title page](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples), named as title-creation. But there is no the .tex for it for modification... How would I render this title page in Latex and combine it with my code?[image]

My code for the thesis is as follows. The title page should be compatible with `\documentclass{report}`. In addition, **I want to arrange the first few pages in the following sequence: title page, dedication page, Acknowledgments, Abstract,
blank page, page for celebrated dictum, table of contents.** Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.7cm,right=2.5cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename \ \thechapter}{15pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-3\baselineskip}{20pt}[3.7cm]

\hyphenpenalty=10000
\tolerance=2500
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{nomentbl}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{setspace}\linespread{1.6}
\setlength\parskip{3pt plus 1.5pt minus 1.5pt}%paragraph

\title{Title of the Thesis}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
%------------------------------------------------------
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
I thank many people here.

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
Here is a short abstract.

\clearpage
\tableofcontents
```

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: Concerning how to do the other pages: where is the problem? There is nothing special about them.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, I have learnt many thing from this link and have modified a titlepage for myself. But this titlepage is only one page file, how could I add a new page because I need a two page titlepage and a dedication page additionally in one tex file.

Comment: @Johannes_B I tried `\clearpage`, which does give a new page but numbering it with _2_. I don't what it to be numbered. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `\pagestyle{empty}`? Ich really don't know where the problem is. Are you a beginner? If so, please read some introductory material.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the real question, but here is my best shot:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,
openright
]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% All modern editors use utf8 by default
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{unnumberedtotoc}% https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.7cm,right=2.5cm}%left and right margins are wrong
\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm,left=1.8cm,headheight=15pt}%left and right margins are better
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{15pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-3\baselineskip}{20pt}[3.7cm]% Moves the chapter title out of the text block. Do you really want this?
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}

%\hyphenpenalty=10000% Commented out, doesn't do any good.
%\tolerance=2500
%\raggedbottom

\usepackage{nomentbl}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{setspace}\linespread{1.6}
%\setlength\parskip{3pt plus 1.5pt minus 1.5pt}%paragraph
\usepackage{parskip}

%\title{Title of the Thesis}% not needed if the titlepage is done by hand

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
%------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-1x1}\par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Columbidae University \par}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large Final year project\par}
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    {\huge\bfseries Pigeons love doves\par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Large\itshape \textsc{jsxs}\par}
    \vfill
    supervised by\par
    Dr.~Mark \textsc{Brown}

    \vfill

% Bottom of the page
    {\large \today\par}
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
\vspace*{.3\textheight}
\hfill I dedicate this thesis to my pet Wombat called Walther.
\addchap{Acknowledgments}
I thank many people here.

\addchap{Abstract}
Here is a short abstract.

\cleardoublepage
Celebrated dictum is on this page
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}\pagestyle{fancy}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{fancy}

\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[5]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```